# Scaling a fixed SurfaceView to fill vertically and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: android, surfaceview

I've been trying to look for an answer and can't seem to find one (it's a fairly unconventional approach to programming an android game, so it's to be expected, at least I think).

I'm trying to create a GBA-style RPG game in Android (for the nostalgia). OpenGL wasn't good enough for me because it wasn't customizable enough in the game loop (I only want draw to be called when there's something that needs to be drawn, since I want this game to be uber-efficient in how it uses the battery, which means making it act more like a polling app than a game). I created a custom surface view with its own thread that gets called whenever drawing needs to be done (I modeled it after the sample LunarLander android game in the SDK).

The thing is, I want the game itself to be a fixed size (208x160) and then scale up to the size of the screen. The problem I'm having is there doesn't seem to be anyway to do so from within the normal parameters of the extended SurfaceView in XML. The game in its current state is illustrated below. I'm trying to make it stretch to the height of the screen and maintain ratio on the width, while also not adding to the viewable game (keeping it fixed, regardless of screen size).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWIdE.png (I was going to post the actual image in-line. Spam prevention can bite me >.<)

Currently I'm getting the SurfaceView's canvas and drawing directly to it, and supplying my size as a hard-coded pixel dimension (208px, 160px).

This is what the thread currently looks like in getting the canvas and drawing to it. What would be a better way to draw to a canvas without changing the size I want the game to virtually take up?

```
@Override
    public void run()
    {
        Canvas c = null;
        try
        {
            c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (surfaceHolder)
            {
                draw(c);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (c != null)
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
```

The draw method is this (StringBuilder is my own coded Object in the engine):

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{       
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(canvas, Color.BLACK, letters);
    stringBuilder.drawString("Oh, hello there!");
    stringBuilder.setLocation(10, 20);
    stringBuilder.drawString("Why am I so small?");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered scaling your canvas to fit the `SurfaceView`?

Comment: @K-ballo The canvas is coming from the SurfaceView itself.... calling run() (which is the thread's run method) creates a Canvas and then sets the canvas to the SurfaceHolder, which then locks the canvas, I then draw to it and then unlock and post to the View when done.

Unless I read the original code from the LunarLander sample wrong...

Comment: So... ? Can't you just call `scale` on it?

Comment: I tried calling scale, but that only works if I didn't care about the size of the canvas. In this case I do, and the size of the canvas is being set by the view. If I match_parent and then scale, it gets bigger, sure, but the canvas size isn't the size I want it to stay at. Basically, I just want to draw to a fixed size canvas, and then maybe if there's a way to draw that onto another canvas, but scaled, that might work for this.

Comment: Actually, you should draw to a canvas **as if** drawing to a fixed size canvas, but initially call `scale` so that the contents scale appropriately maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: great.. I am devloping a scrable game where board and letter rack is drawing in canvas.. what I want is only to scale board part.. when I cliprect the board part it make other part black.. please help me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume your `draw` function is renamed to `drawBase` instead. Here is how you do it:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    final float scaleFactor = Math.min( getWidth() / 208.f, getHeight() / 160.f );
    final float finalWidth = 208.f * scaleFactor;
    final float finalHeight = 160.f * scaleFactor;
    final float leftPadding = ( getWidth() - finalWidth ) / 2;
    final float topPadding =  ( getHeight() - finalHeight ) / 2;

    final int savedState = canvas.save();
    try {
        canvas.clipRect(leftPadding, topPadding, leftPadding + finalWidth, topPadding + finalHeight);

        canvas.translate(leftPadding, topPadding);
        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

        drawBase(canvas);
    } finally {
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting a canvas from the SurfaceView and the SurfaceView already has a predetermined size from the layout. Though I like this code, it still doesn't create a game view that has a fixed 1.3 ratio with pillar boxes as padding on the sides. There's still extra game on the right side and it's going to be a distraction for the players.

Comment: @TheAssailant: There, adjusted the code for padding and clipping.

Comment: Thank you! This works (almost) perfectly. For what I need I simply set the topMargin to 0 and used the original supplied height for the clipping. Worked like a charm. But yeah, this is perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: after scalling what can be done for scrolling the scale part of the surfaceview.. thanks for your concern...

Answer (score 2):

(The accepted answer from K-ballo is fine, but in the 2.5 years since it was written displays have gotten a lot denser, which means software rendering is increasingly expensive.  It's important to get the hardware to help do the work.)

To render at a specific resolution, you can use [SurfaceHolder#setFixedSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize(int,%20int)).  This sets the size of the Surface to be the exact dimensions you specify.  The surface will be scaled up to match the size of the View by the hardware scaler, which is going to be more efficient than software scaling.  The feature is described in this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html), and you can see it in action in [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "hardware scaler exerciser" activity ([demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpRaD-ij2xc)).

You can maintain the proper aspect ratio for different-sized displays by adjusting the size of the Surface (which is what Grafika does for that demo), or by tweaking the View to letter- or pillar-box the layout.  You can find an example of the latter in Grafika's AspectFrameLayout class, which is used for various camera and video demos.

With regard to this:

> OpenGL wasn't good enough for me because it wasn't customizable enough in the game loop (I only want draw to be called when there's something that needs to be drawn ...

You have two options.  First, you can use [GLSurfaceView#setRenderMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderMode(int)) to disable continuous rendering.  Second, you don't need to use GLSurfaceView to use OpenGL.  Most of the GLES code in Grafika operates on SurfaceView or TextureView.